# Combinatorics with multiple design rules (e.g. no more than X instances, no more than X contiguous instances, etc.)

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, combinatorial-designs

I am struggling with a biochemistry question that when broken down is  just a mathematics combinatorics problem. Hopefully this type of question is allowed on this Stack Exchange (apologies if it is not!).

I am trying to figure out every possible combination of a sequence of characters (chemical modifications on nucleotides) given a set of design constraints (to minimize toxicity and stability). To remove the requirement of domain expertise, I will simplify the problem to a combination of a characters in a string.

The string sequence must have 23 character combinations of `[A, B, C, D, E]`. The order of the characters in the sequence matter. The distribution of each character is not important, but the sequence must follow all the rules below:

- There can be at most 6 instances of `A` anywhere in the sequence.
- There can be at most 13 instances of `A` or `B` anywhere in the sequence.
- There cannot be more than 2 consecutive instances of `C` (e.g. `..ACCD..` is allowed, while `..ACCCD..` is not allowed) -- this rule only applies to `C`.

How many combinations can be designed?

I know without any design rules, there are `5^23` combinations. I think I can figure out the number of combinations given one rule by subtracting all sequences of that rule from `5^23`. However, I am stumped when there are multiple rules in play. I suspect I will have to make a Venn diagram and calculate all the overlaps, but I wonder if there is a different way to tackle this problem? I feel like this can be solved exactly, but if the problem is too specific (or complex to solve), is there at least a way I can make a rough estimate with some logical justification? I appreciate any input on this problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can count the number of valid sequences exactly, with the help of a computer.

For each integer $k\in \{1,2,\dots,16\}$, we will find the number of sequences which have exactly $k$ `C`'s, then sum over $k$. Our strategy is to first place the `C`'s, then to place the other letters.

To place the `C`'s, we need to choose a subset of $\{1,\dots,23\}$ with $k$ elements which has no three consecutive elements. In general, let $f(n,k)$ be the number of ways to choose a subset of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ with $k$ elements, no $3$ consecutive. You can prove that
$$
f(n,k)=f(n-1,k)+f(n-2,k-1)+f(n-3,k-2) \qquad (n\ge 3,k\ge 2)
$$
This recurrence allows you to compute $f(23,k)$ with a computer, using dynamic programming.

Once the `C`'s are placed, there are $23-k$ slots remaining, to be filled with `A`'s, `B`'s, `D`'s, and `E`'s. If the number of `A`'s is $i$, then the `A`'s can be placed in $\binom{23-k}i$ ways. Then, if the number of `B`'s is $j$, the `B`'s can be placed in the remaining spots in $\binom{23-k-i}{j}$ ways. Finally, the remaining $23-k-i-j$ spots can be filled with `D` and `E` in $2^{23-k-i-j}$ ways. You then need to sum over all possible $i$ and $j$ which satisfy $0\le i\le 6$ and $0\le i+j\le 13$.

Putting this all together, the number of valid sequences is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{16}\sum_{i=0}^6\sum_{j=0}^{13-i}f(23,k)\binom {23-k}i\binom{23-k-i}j2^{23-k-i-j}
$$
I found that there were about $8.47\times 10^{15}$ valid sequences, which is about $71\%$ of the total number, using [this Python code](https://tio.run/##XY/LboMwEEXX@Cuu1A0moASjdoGC1C/orusKOXbjENvIGKnNz1NjyKusuHOGO4f@1x@tqaZJOqshR8O9tecBSvfWeZzd@MVbfhSEHIQEP1o7iNTkHa1JoiQMsMeuhhN@dAa7OOywbx6GHZpmJuI8iBrxWcm1rijzrigpstC33aIj5P12ONXtz6AuAg0@rBEUL/gcBLTQVl1ar6zJ4S2GXogDxh7c6n70EURl@WQbxBisWxTLGiRJ/rmE5VX1zuSiSLGJr2yxXUIVAqOEtJyPGvOPytivDFxrvkVavoXNcjaYgbqD2zyC08MXFYqweKXJUr1pwj0WztFsdWVV0eXqKRYqP9GMZdmaihMlvVPGp7HkKWxfs4xVdJr@AA)

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer! I'm going to need more time to digest your solution, but I already gave an upvote for now (and on the verge of marking it as the accepted answer). My main question is where the 16 comes from in the equation? I see that it's related to the rule for `C`, but I might be too obtuse to understand why?

Comment: @JasonKLai That is the largest number of possible `C`'s, which is attained by `CC*CC*CC*CC*CC*CC*CC*CC`. Any more, and you would have three consecutive.

Comment: Great, thank you for following-up. The Python code was also a nice touch on the answer!

Answer (score 4):

We consider a $5$-ary alphabet built from letters $\{A,B,C,D,E\}$. Words which do not have *any* consecutive equal letters are called *Smirnov words*. A generating function for Smirnov words is given as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\left(1-\frac{5z}{1+5z}\right)^{-1}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
The coefficient $[z^n]$ of $z^n$ in the series (1) gives the number of $5$-ary words of length $n$ which do not have any consecutive letters.

> In the current example we are looking for words which do not contain a *bad* word from $\{CCC\}$ and where the number of occurrences of $A$ is at most $6$ and the number of occurrences with $A$ together with $B$ is at most $13$. The letters $D$ and $E$ do not have any restriction at all. We use (1) as basis and perform following substitutions:
>
> \begin{align*}
> z&\quad\to\quad sz+s^2z^2+\cdots=\color{blue}{\frac{sz}{1-sz}}\tag{$\to\ A$}\\
> z&\quad\to\quad tz+t^2z^2+\cdots=\color{blue}{\frac{tz}{1-tz}}\tag{$\to\ B$}\\
> z&\quad\to\quad z+z^2=\color{blue}{z(1+z)}\tag{$\to\ C$}\\
> z&\quad\to\quad z+z^2+\cdots=\color{blue}{\frac{z}{1-z}}\tag{$\to\ D, E$}\\
> \end{align*}

- The number of occurrences of $A$ is allowed to be at most $6$. We mark each occurrence of $A$ with $s$ to respect this in the calculation.
- We also want no more than $13$ occurrences of $A$ and $B$. Therefore we mark occurrences of $B$ with $t$.
- We substitute occurrences of $C$ by $z+z^2$ avoiding this way runs of $C$ of length $3$.
- Since there are no restrictions for $D$'s and $E$'s, we substitute $z$ with $z+z^2+\cdots=\frac{1}{1-z}$ for these two cases.

> We transform (1) performing the substitutions given above and obtain with some help of Wolfram Alpha
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{A(z;s,t)}&=\left(1-\frac{\frac{sz}{1-sz}}{1+\frac{sz}{1-sz}}-\frac{\frac{tz}{1-tz}}{1+\frac{tz}{1-tz}}\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\left.-\frac{z(1+z)}{1+z(1+z)}-\frac{2\frac{z}{1-z}}{1+\frac{z}{1-z}}\right)^{-1}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\left(1-(s+t)z-\frac{3z+3z^2+2z^3}{1+z+z^2}\right)^{-1}}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
> The wanted number is
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{6}\sum_{j=0}^{13-k}[z^{23}s^kt^j]A(z;s,t)}
> &\color{blue}{= 8\,472\,450\,413\,729\,761}\\
> &\color{blue}{\doteq 8.472\cdot 10^{15}}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with the result of @MikeEarnest. The calculation was done thanks to the support of @MikeEarnest with *[this Mathematica code](https://tio.run/##HY7BCoMwEETv@Yo9GlRaE@ihpYfSHyj0KFGCRLqCFkx6Ufz2dJLD7jxmlkxmGz5utoEHG@Oj3fqKPCb0hq53KhqqqfBUUpC0JdaQkrA7BVVQLU84K7MPV8quqBt5E@K18hJaQfT@zUkAbmXnn183jjywQ4pGFKLPVLQDzxUpfYB9Zk4YMk4HTvIrO2fjkrIpY6PxNT6QGmFi/AM)*.

**Note:** Smirnow words can be found for instance in example III.24 in  *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf)* by P. Flajolet and R. Sedgewick.

Comment: @MikeEarnest: Ah, I see. You're right. Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I will correct it.

Comment: nice answer..................+1

Comment: [Mathematica confirms that your answer and mine agree!](https://tio.run/##HY7BCoMwEETv@Yo9GlRaE@ihpYfSHyj0KFGCRLqCFkx6Ufz2dJLD7jxmlkxmGz5utoEHG@Oj3fqKPCb0hq53KhqqqfBUUpC0JdaQkrA7BVVQLU84K7MPV8quqBt5E@K18hJaQfT@zUkAbmXnn183jjywQ4pGFKLPVLQDzxUpfYB9Zk4YMk4HTvIrO2fjkrIpY6PxNT6QGmFi/AM)

Comment: @MikeEarnest: Ah, great! Many thanks for this verification. :-)